# Pandas merge on variable columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table of sites with a land cover *class* and a *state*. I have another table with values linked to *class* and *state*. In the second table, however, some of the rows are linked only to *class*:

```
sites = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                      'class': [1, 2, 23],
                      'state': ['al', 'ar', 'wy']})

values = pd.DataFrame({'class': [1, 1, 2, 2, 23],
                       'state': ['al', 'ar', 'al', 'ar', None],
                       'val': [10, 11, 12, 13, 16]})
```

I'd like to link the tables by *class* and *state*, except for those rows in the value table for which *state* is None, in which case they would be linked only by *class*.

A merge has the following result:

```
combined = sites.merge(values, how='left', on=['class', 'state'])

  id  class state   val
0  a      1    al  10.0
1  b      2    ar  13.0
2  c     23    wy   NaN
```

But I'd like *val* in the last row to be 16.  Is there an inexpensive way to do this short of breaking up both tables, performing separate merges, and then concatenating the result?

Comment: column `cdl` does not exists

Comment: cdl is class .. I have edited his question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about merge them separately:

```
pd.concat([sites.merge(values, on=['class','state']),
           sites.merge(values[values['state'].isna()].drop('state',axis=1),
                       on=['class'])
          ])
```

Output:

```
  id  class state  val
0  a      1    al   10
1  b      2    ar   13
0  c     23    wy   16
```

Comment: Both this answer and the answer by anky_91 work, but this one is slightly faster

Answer (score 3):

We can use [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) here:

```
(sites.set_index(['class','state'])
  .combine_first(values.set_index(['class','state']))
  .dropna().reset_index())
```

---

```
   class state id   val
0      1    al  a  10.0
1      2    ar  b  13.0
2     23    wy  c  16.0
```